# Bootstrap XSS attack on Popovers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xss

I've read [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) that I can enable HTML in a popover, which can be a potential issue for XSS attacks.

In my case popovers will contain nothing like forms or the like, but only text or links or tables or images.

Can I use them safely without incurring in XSS attacks?

Thank you!

SN

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you're the one providing the html it's safe to use them. It's only unsafe to enable html when the content comes from user input and isn't sanitized beforehand.